# How to use node-modules installed by npm from template

Tags: go, npm, three.js

I am trying to use a library installed by npm in the Go template.

I installed the necessary three libraries through 'npm install three', saved in the root folder as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

After that, I try to import and use the three.js module as shown below, but threejs is not found.

I think there is some problem with the filesystem, how can I use threejs without problems in my situation?

```
import * as THREE from "/three";

class App{
    constructor(){
        // 장면
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // 카메라
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

        // 렌더러
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
    new App();
}
```

error

import * as THREE from "/three";

```
http://localhost:8081/three net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

import * as THREE from "three";

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

e.Static("/node", "node_modules") in main.go

import * as THREE from "/node/node_modules/three/builld/three.module.js";

```
GET http://localhost:8081/node/three/builld/three.module.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: there is a typo in your code? I believe it's suppose to be `build` and not `builld`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="importmap">
    {
        "imports": {
            "three": "/node/three/build/three.module.js"
        }
    }
</script>
```

It was resolved by correcting the path to the job.